# quickblox new token after sign in with facebook

Tags: quickblox

Why when user is signing in with Facebook([QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" scope:@[@"publish_stream"] delegate:self]), session token changes? And how i can get this new session token?

Answer (score 0):

After logging in in delegate you specified method completedWithResult: will be fired. This method will get object of class QBUUserLogInResult, which contains socialProviderToken field. This is your new session token.